# roundcube mssql setup

Tags: php, windows, open-source, roundcube, mail-server

Installing roundcube webmail: I have the DB set up (win serv 2008, MS SQL 2008 - though even that was a battle!) i can navigate to the installer but when I go to set up everything there is no SQL Server option in the list of DBs?

Anyone got any idea what thats all about? I can see MySql, MySqli and PgSql but no MSSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've activated the MSSQL extension in your php.ini. I don't know this script, but often installers first detect which database extensions are available and let you only use these.

So find your php.ini and search it for something like this:

```
extension=msql.dll
```

If you can't find the line, add it to the file (maybe restart your webserver) and try again.

Comment: yeah - i have that - do i need to download the dll or something? i've even restarted the server - nothign...

Comment: I think it's part of the default package, so if PHP doesn't complain about it, it's probably there. Maybe check `phpinfo()` too, to see if it's really loaded. Haven't got any other ideas, sorry.

Comment: http://mail.projectattack.co.uk/test.php

Comment: The MSSQL extension isn't loaded. Make sure there's no `;` in front of the line mentioned in the answer (just to be sure :). I never installed PHP on Win, but on Linux there are seperate php.inis for CGI and CLI mode, are you sure you've picked the right one?

Comment: def no semicolon and there seems to be only one .ini? hectic central :)

Comment: It's not loaded. You could try the Microsoft MSSQL driver too, although that's another set of functions than the "regular" mssql functions in PHP. Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc299381.aspx - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296203%28SQL.90%29.aspx But that's just a wild guess, you're on your own now.

Answer (score 1):

Roundcube installer doesn't detect mssql!

Select with mysql option while you are install ms sql driver for php.
there is a complete installation guide http://www.ifunky.net/Blog/post/How-To-Install-RoundCube-With-hMailServer-and-Windows-2008-IIS7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's because Roundcube Installer doesn't detect MSSQL, but you can install/run it without Installer.

Comment: I've changed the DB to now use MySql but it's still not working!! aarrgghh!!

Comment: alec, some details would really be helpfull... what should we use for the $rcmail_config['db_dsnw']? if I have a named instance, how do I put the instance name in there?